# Tag score not showing up on profile?

Tags: support, user-profile

I am not sure if this is the right site to post this question. When I go to my Arqade public profile, the score for my top tags isn't showing up. My top tag right now is [bomber-crew](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bomber-crew) and it says that I have a total of 2 posts on it, but I have no score on it.

I have gotten 1 upvote on one of my questions with the tag but it will not show up. Does the question have to be marked as closed or complete so I get a score on the tag?

Comment: I don't know for sure currently, but I am willing to bet there's likely a script or somesuch that needs to run for that to update, and I suspect it runs only once a day or some other similar time interval, so it might just take time.

Comment: Ok, but i have a super smash bros question with 2 upvotes from about a week ago and that hasn't loaded in yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only non-wiki answer score is shown next to tag on main profile page.

For example, for my top tag explanation says:

> Asked 5 non-wiki questions with a total score of 31. Gave 17 non-wiki answers with a total score of 95.

And score next to it shows 95.

Also, as Ash mentioned in comments, script runs on some time interval, so changes are reflected only after some time. I think soon you will have score 1 for [bomber-crew](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bomber-crew), but still 0 for [super-smash-bros-ultimate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-smash-bros-ultimate) as you have no answers for it yet.

Comment: So you only get points for answers, not questions?

Comment: @unicornturtle you get reputation points for questions too. But on profile page in Top Tags only answer score is shown.